# pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Reading lists of structs from Parquet files not yet supported: paygw_etp_typs: list<array: struct

Tags: python, pandas, validation, pyarrow, great-expectations

I am using Great Expectations to test data within ETL pipelines. The data file I have, it is in Parquet format and does have some Arrays, when I am trying to create to new suite or try to convert into readable format using pyarrow/fastparquet I am facing below error:[image]  However it's all working OK for other Parquet data file those does not have Arrays struct in it.

I am using AWS cloud 9 as an IDE and unable to resolve this issue. Any help would be highly appreciated. Please guide me in right way how can I handle those Arrays in my parquet data file ?? I have tried  almost everything but NO LUCK :(

Comment: It's a know issue, that is resolved in arrow 2.0.0, you should try upgrading if you can.

Comment: thanks for reply :) I did upgrade pyarrow to 2.0.0 successfully, but when i run python script to convert it just stuck without giving any errors, and i had to cancel the operation eventually.

Comment: IT WORKED !!! but took almost an hour :)